# How to Insert Large String(10000 Character String) into excel Sheet using Oledb Query

Tags: c#, windows

I created web application, in this application there is a part of insert Large string (String having more than 10000 characters) values in to excel sheet using oledb query.
i have tried the below code but i am getting

> "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to
>   add.  Try inserting or pasting less data." this error.

```
string con = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Test.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
            {
                connection.Open();
                // string str = "bsdhjbdshjfbdhjsfsbjfsbfhjsfbjhbfjhbfjhsbhfshjfjfbjhfjshfjhsfjshfjdhsfjsjfdsjfj";
                string str = "bsdhjbfdggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggdfgdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddshjfbdhjsfsbjfsbfhjsfbjhbfjhbfjhsbhfshjfjfbjhfjshfjhsfjshfjdhsfjsjfdsjfjjglfgjlkjgoig/dfdfgflkdglkfgfjlkgkjldfglklfggjoitglklkfjdgoidjgldmgldgogloieewrlkrj/k.asuhdidkahdsdhisuahdiuhsikudhiusadhiusdhishdisiduhidhsihahudihiuhisahdiuhiai";
                string sqlStquery = "Insert into [Sheet1$] ([ID],[Name]) Values ('" + 0 + "','" + str + "')";

                OleDbDataAdapter dbadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStquery, connection);
                dbadapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dbadapter.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
            }
```

so can any one suggest me how to insert more than 10000 character string value into Excel sheet using Oledb Query.

Comment: i have tried. i will add my code into the Question.

Comment: In your connection string there is Excel 8.0. Are your really targeting Excel 97?